# Сравнение тегов элементов на форме

Tags: form, button, типы-данных, теги

У меня есть кнопка, Tag которой равен 1. Мне нужно сравнить этот тег с тегом остальных кнопок (2, 3, 4 и т.д.) пока не найду наибольший. Пытался присвоить тег переменной типа int - не получилось. Может вы знаете способ это сделать?

Вот весь код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конце tag2 равен 1000, а у меня 3 кнопки с соответствующими тегами.

Comment: Как Вы присваиваете значения свойств `Tag`?

Comment: @Igor добавил весь код, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Нет кода, который присваивает/увеличивает значение переменной `lastTag`. Каким образом `lastTag` становится равен 1000?

Comment: @Igor "if (lastTag < tag1) lastTag = tag1;" тут присваиваю значение переменной lastTag. Дальше она присваивается тегу созданной кнопки, и когда я проверяю тег там 1000, а должно быть 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(Control pb in Controls)
{
  if (pb is Button) 
  {
    int tag1 = 0;
    if (pb.Tag is int)
      tag1 = (int)pb.Tag;
    else if (pb.Tag is string)
      int.TryParse((string)pb.Tag, out tag1);

    if (lastTag < tag1)
    {
      lastTag = tag1;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Вячеслав, я не понимаю, откуда у Вас берется число 1000. `lastTag` - это член класса формы? Сделайте его свойством:

```
private int mLastTag;
private int lastTag
{
  get { return mLastTag; }
  set
  {
    mLastTag = value;
  }
}
```

и поставьте breakpoint на строчку `mLastTag = value;`.

Comment: Ошибка: "object" не содержит определиеня для Tag
Как исправить?

Comment: @Vyacheslav - Пардон? Никакую.

Comment: "(возможно пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)"

Comment: Обозначьте явный тип для `pb` в `foreach` (см. измененный код).

Comment: lastTag в результате разве должен быть 0? Или это у меня ошибка?

Comment: Как Вы присваиваете значения свойств `Tag` контролов/кнопок?  (см. измененный код)

Comment: Проверю ваш код завтра, если не выйдет отпишусь и скину свой код, спасибо что помогаете

Comment: Брейкпоинт должен быть с условием, как я понял, "lastTag != 1000", но условие не истинно, и точка остановки активируется. Или я должен был что-то другое в брейкпоинте указать?

Comment: @ Igor извините меня за мою тупость, вся проблема была в скрытой кнопке о которой я забыл, там то и стоял Тег 1000. Я вам очень благодарен за все что вы для меня сделали!